# 'code' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I'm doing cs50p and I am using visual studio.
In the first tutorial they are using command "code hello.py" in terminal and it should create a file but I'm getting only errors, saying the powershell doesn't understand comand "code"

```
code : The term 'code' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the        heck the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ code hello.py
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (code:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: Removed Python tag since your error is specific to running code command

Comment: This is not really a question about programming, but about using your computer. You need to understand the PATH environment variable.

Answer (score -2):

just type "touch hello.py" in your terminal.

Comment: Didn't downvote, but Powershell does not have a `touch` command.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).